# How to set two xml's for one activity?If i select one option i have to get one xml and vice versa?

Tags: android, xml, view

[image: Twoviews_one activity]

If i select "New customer" in customertype spinner(spn_cust) i have to  show a view containing button,Spinner,Editext,textview.If i select "Existing Customer" i have to get another view conatining Button,Editext.
How is it possible?Should i hide one xml while selecting one option?Programatically how will i solve this issue??

```
pncustomertype.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long arg3) {
            //String item = spncustomertype.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();



        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Comment: Use `LayoutInflater`.

Comment: You can create it in one xml and keep hide and according to the selecting thing in the spinner visible the view that is more better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many available solutions:

1. The easiest: `findViewbyID` and `setVisibility` to your buttons
2. Create different xml layouts and combine them with `include` tag, `setVisibility` on event.
3. Create different xml layouts, use `LayoutInflater` to inflate each xml file and add it by code

Comment: You can keep Include TAG inside ViewStub, so Include TAG will not included while designing layout of screen. It will improve your layout performance. Depending on the selection you can set visibility of ViewStub to Visible or Gone.

Answer (score 0):

If the operations associated with the elements(i.e Button,edittext etc) are different depending on the option selected(New customer or Existing Customer), its better to create two different view classes View1(containing Button,Spinner,Edittext,Textview) and View2(containing Button,Edittext).

```html
public class View1 extends RelativeLayout{
//put your code and use 
//View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.YOUR_LAYOUT, this); to inflate your layout
}
```

```html
 public class View2 extends RelativeLayout{
    //put your code and use 
    //View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.YOUR_LAYOUT, this); to inflate your layout
    }
```

Now add these views to the viewgroup(ex. Linearlayout, RelativeLayout etc) as,
viewgroup.addView(View1/View2) depending on your selection(New customer or Existing Customer).

Answer (score 0):

```
You can do it by setting visibilities in xml and code. 
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp" 
tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:text="edit_Text"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:visibility="gone"/>


</RelativeLayout>

package com.example.user.spinnerapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends Activity{
private Button button;
   private  Spinner spinner;
    private EditText editText;
    private TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final List<String> spinnerArray =  new ArrayList<>();
        spinnerArray.add("New Customer");
        spinnerArray.add("Existing Customer");

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray);

       // adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        final Spinner sItems = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

        sItems.setAdapter(adapter);



       sItems.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
           @Override
           public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

               //String selected = spinnerArray.get(position);
               String selected = sItems.getSelectedItem().toString();

               if (selected.equals("New Customer")) {
                   button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                   spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                   editText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                   textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

               }
               else if(selected.equals("Existing Customer")){

                   spinner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                   textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
               }
           }

           @Override
           public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

           }
       });



    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

To set 2 xmls
create xml with required fields and inflate them as per your conditions.